# Angular close a bootstrap modal conditionally

Tags: javascript, angular, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I have this modal in an Angular app:

```html
<ng-template #content let-modal>
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h2 class="modal-title" id="modal-basic-title">{{saveTitle}}</h2>
    <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="modal.dismiss('Cross click')">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <app-add-program [model]="model" [showNavBar]="false" title=""></app-add-program>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark" (click)="modal.close('Save click')">{{saveButtonTitle}}</button>
  </div>
</ng-template>
```

I don't think the `app-add-program` component is really necessary to answer this question but if you need to see it let me know.

This is the open function for that modal:

```js
  open(content): void {
    // @ts-ignore
    this.modalReference = this.modalService.open(content, {ariaLabelledBy: 'modal'}).result.then((result) => {
      this.pds.programCast.subscribe((data) => {
          if (result === 'Save click'){
            const editedProgram = data;
            console.log('Edited program: ', editedProgram);
            const validity = this.programService.validateModel(editedProgram);
            console.log('Validity check...');
            if (validity.isValid === true) {
              console.log('Validity was true.');
              // If the program needs to be approved and activated then mark it approved
              if (editedProgram?.approved === false){
                editedProgram.approved = true;
              }
              if (editedProgram?.active === false){
                editedProgram.active = true;
              }
              console.log(editedProgram);
              console.log('Starting api call...');
              if (editedProgram != null && editedProgram !== undefined) {
                this.programService.editProgram(editedProgram).subscribe({
                  // tslint:disable-next-line:no-shadowed-variable
                  next: result => {
                    this.wasSuccessful = true;
                    console.log('It was successful');
                    this.snackBar.open('Your changes have been saved.');
                    this.modalReference.close();
                  },
                  error: err => {
                    this.wasSuccessful = false;
                    console.log('It failed: ', err.statusText);
                    this.snackBar.open('There was an error saving your changes. Error Status ' + err.status + ': ' + err.statusText);
                  }
                });
              }
            } else {
              console.log('Validity was false.');
              this.snackBar.open(validity.reason);
            }
          } else {
            this.closeResult = `Closed with: ${result}`;
          }
      });
    }, (reason) => {
      this.closeResult = `Dismissed ${this.getDismissReason(reason)}`;
    });
  }
```

What I want is rather than calling `modal.close` in the html call a function instead that makes the API call and either close the modal with `this.modalReference.close()` if it was successful or leave the modal open if it was not successful.

So basically, this section needs to execute:

```js
     const editedProgram = data;
            console.log('Edited program: ', editedProgram);
            const validity = this.programService.validateModel(editedProgram);
            console.log('Validity check...');
            if (validity.isValid === true) {
              console.log('Validity was true.');
              // If the program needs to be approved and activated then mark it approved
              if (editedProgram?.approved === false){
                editedProgram.approved = true;
              }
              if (editedProgram?.active === false){
                editedProgram.active = true;
              }
              console.log(editedProgram);
              console.log('Starting api call...');
              if (editedProgram != null && editedProgram !== undefined) {
                this.programService.editProgram(editedProgram).subscribe({
                  // tslint:disable-next-line:no-shadowed-variable
                  next: result => {
                    this.wasSuccessful = true;
                    console.log('It was successful');
                    this.snackBar.open('Your changes have been saved.');
                    this.modalReference.close();
                  },
                  error: err => {
                    this.wasSuccessful = false;
                    console.log('It failed: ', err.statusText);
                    this.snackBar.open('There was an error saving your changes. Error Status ' + err.status + ': ' + err.statusText);
                  }
                });
              }
            } else {
              console.log('Validity was false.');
              this.snackBar.open(validity.reason);
            }
```

and then in the `next` clause call `this.modalReference.close()` or leave it open and present the pop up message that it shows in the `error` clause.

I know that I have most of the code written already but for some reason I just can't work out in my head how to write the code to execute in that order.

If you need any further info to answer this question please let me know.

UPDATE:

```
open(content): void {
    // @ts-ignore
    this.modalReference = this.modalService.open(content, {ariaLabelledBy: 'modal'}).result;
  }
```

```
  private validateAndSave(closeReason) {
    if (closeReason === 'Save click') {
        const editedProgram = this.model;
        console.log('Model: ', this.model);
        console.log('Edited program: ', editedProgram);
        if (editedProgram != null && editedProgram !== undefined) {
          const validity = this.programService.validateModel(editedProgram);
          if (validity.isValid === true) {
            console.log('Validity was true.');
            // If the program needs to be approved and activated then mark it approved
            if (editedProgram?.approved === false) {
              editedProgram.approved = true;
            }
            if (editedProgram?.active === false) {
              editedProgram.active = true;
            }
            this.programService.editProgram(editedProgram).subscribe({
              next: result => {
                this.wasSuccessful = true;
                console.log('It was successful: ', result);
                this.snackBar.open('Your changes have been saved.');
                this.modalReference.close();
              },
              error: err => {
                this.wasSuccessful = false;
                console.log('It failed: ', err.statusText);
                this.snackBar.open('There was an error saving your changes. Error Status ' + err.status + ': ' + err.statusText);
              }
            });
          } else {
            console.log('Validity was false.');
            this.snackBar.open(validity.reason);
          }
        }
    } else {
      this.modalReference.close();
    }
  }
```

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark" (click)="validateAndSave('Save click')">{{saveButtonTitle}}</button>
```

I believe that I have done everything that the first answer recommended but I am getting this error when trying to close the modal:

```
[Error] ERROR – TypeError: _this.modalReference.close is not a function.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are executing all your code in the `resolve` path of your modal.

To avoid that, simply create a new function (`validateAndSave` or something like that) and move all the logic starting from the third line of your `open` function

That would be this part:

```js
this.pds.programCast.subscribe((data) => {...}
```

But you have to remove the first `if` of that block, the one that checks:

```js
if (result === 'Save click') {...}
```

So, when you reach your `wasSuccessful` case, you simply call `this.modalReference.close()`

Finally, in your template you call the `validateAndSave` function instead of the `modal.close`:

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark" (click)="validateAndSave()">{{saveButtonTitle}}</button>
```

Don't forget to remove the `.then` part of your opening modal line, so it will only open the modal and store the reference in `this.modalReference`

Comment: I love this answer and I have tried to make it work. Please check out the update I made and see if you can help me find a workaround.

Comment: That error occurs because you are assigning the `result` to the reference. Remove the `.result` part and try again:
```typescript
this.modalReference = this.modalService.open(content, {ariaLabelledBy: 'modal'});
```